# jQuery conditions: multiple radio buttons in different fields

Tags: jquery, forms, conditional-statements, radio-button

I want an image source to change upon clicking specific radio buttons in different fields. The below snippet works for one option (when the user selects white for example).

Now he can select 'round' or 'cornered' in a different field. How do I now tell jQuery to change the src when white AND round is clicked?

```js
jQuery("input[name=input_3]").click(function() {
    if (jQuery("input[value=white]").prop("checked")) {
        jQuery('#ringimage').fadeOut(200, function() {
            jQuery("#ringimage").attr('src', 'white.jpg');
        }).fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, share a jsfiddle! :-)

Comment: How many possible combinations are there?  Just 2 colors and 2 styles?

Comment: wheres your html??

Answer (score 0):

If there are corresponding file names for all the values, you can code:

```
$("input[name=input_3]").change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $('#ringimage').stop().fadeOut(200, function() {
       $(this).attr('src', val + '.jpg');
    }).fadeIn(200);
});
```

If this is not the case, you can use an object for getting the file names:

```
var paths = {
  'val1': 'white.jpg',
  'val2': 'blue.jpg'
}

$("input[name=input_3]").change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $('#ringimage').stop().fadeOut(200, function() {
       $(this).attr('src', paths[val]);
    }).fadeIn(200);
});
```